# DPR not working on firefox/chrome inspector

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

My last question was closed for some reasons ([Chrome Inspector not even 1% accurate to real mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607028/chrome-inspector-not-even-1-accurate-to-real-mobile-devices))

However as it seems the problem was related to the DPR. I will attach images to show my problem

Chrome/Firefox Inspector with DPR 2.0 for Iphone 6/7/8:
[image: alt tag]

Real Iphone 6:
[image: alt tag]

I can not simulate the DPR on any website on any browser on my pc or my friends pc. It will always scale like 1. Doesnt matter if I use DPR 1,2 or 3.

So my questions is how to successfully simulate DPR 2.0?

I guess the problem is DPR or is it something else?

Comment: What are you expecting exactly?

Comment: That I can see the exact same zoom/viewport on my pc inspector like you can see there on the real iphone device. I want to simulate this second picture. As far as I understand you use DPR for it. However as you can see in image 1 nothing is changing and I can´t simulate DPR 2

Comment: The pixel ratio affects how images are displayed; it is separate from device nominal pixel resolution.

Comment: well this doesn´t help me. I want to simulate real smartphone display on my desktop inspector. As written in my closed post my complete website is designed wrong because on real smartphones everything looks different and you can´t simulate it with chrome/firefox as related to the pictures above which clearly shows the problem. also the text in the images is also in 2 lines instead of 1 so it doesnt only affects images as you say. The complete layout gets zoom on any website.

Comment: You *can't* simulate real smartphone display. The way that higher-pixel displays work is that they tell the web browser a *fictional* resolution that's smaller than the *actual* resolution. Your website really can't do anything with the actual physical native resolution outside of what can be done with `<img>` tags.

Comment: I can´t really believe that people just design their website in chrome inspector and then just hope that it works well on real smartphone cause they can´t simulate real smartphone displays as you say. Why can you not simulate the fictional resulation with zoom or something like this? I mean how should I design my website for iphone 6 when I can´t get the actually resolution on my desktop inspector?

Comment: What's your exact question about this? How to use a simulator? If you need help to fix the problem, you should also share some code such that others could reproduce the problem

Comment: @NicoHaase I don´t believe you understand the problem. There is no code problem. I want to simulate **real smartphone display resolutions** on my desktop browser inspector without getting 2 different layouts as shown in the linked images from above.

Comment: So, if there is no code problem, how should anybody help you? Searching for the proper tools to simulate something is off-topic here

Comment: I don´t search for any tools I search for a **css code/inspector fixes** to simulate **real smartphone display resolutions** on my desktop browser inspector without getting 2 different layouts as shown in the linked images from above.

Comment: As long as you don't provide any details about this error, there is no way anybody can reproduce it and provide help. Also, as @Pointy already wrote: this is difficult to simulate.

Comment: What error you want to have. Use your smartphone and open youtube, then go chrome and choose device emulation of your smartphone you used and you will see the difference like in the screens above. I can´t really believe that all web designer on this planet use services like browserstack to design their websites for mobile. For what reason you even have inspector mobile device emulation when it´s not even 1% accurate to real smartphone resolutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the bigger text was my bad, my iphone got bigger text set that was the reason why the text was different. However the core of this topic is still the same and the resolution is different to chrome inspector and real devices. However mostly because of the browser taskbars.

As it seems no browser related inspector solution is working. However even when some people said it is not possible to emulate real devices it´s actually possible and also by google itself with android studio:

- https://developer.android.com/studio

You can use any android version and create any resolution you want. You can also test localhost from your host os inside of your emulated smartphone browser by using this instead of the default localhost/127.0.0.1:

- 10.0.2.2

You can also open inspector of your emulated device from your main os! By using:

- chrome://inspect/#devices

And here is starting the real question. Why does this inspector window clone the correct device resolution from the emulated device? I mean it´s literally the default chrome inspector window again. Very confusing.

They even clone the menubar, even when it´s now showing, the resolution and everything else was cloned 1to1 compared to the android studio emulator.

However I guess it´s more realtime streaming than actually cloning.

[image: alt tag]

That´s to the point it´s not possible..

---

Also maybe very nice to know that you can use the fullscreen API to dodge problems with those annoying browser taskbars which crash your ui and take space. You can use this code to enter fullscreen with user gesture:

```html
<button id="goFS">Go fullscreen</button>
<script>
 $("#goFS").on("click",function(){
      
   // this works with scroll -  do not use document.body.requestFullscreen();   
   const elem = document.documentElement;
   if (elem.requestFullscreen) {elem.requestFullscreen()}

      if(document.fullscreenElement){
      console.log('fullscreen detected');
      }

  
 });
</script>
```

---

In fact it´s really sad that you have to download android developer software just to emulate real display solutions as web designer. I hope google will build in this technology in future inside of their chrome inspector.

Also I guess apple is providing the same software for their ios app development. So you should be able to emulate iphones their too. However as far as I read you must use a MAC machine for this.

Hope this will help anybody.